# Setting A Member of Generic Object?

Tags: c#, reflection, generics

```
public class myclass 
{
    public int mymember { get; set; }  
}

class MySetterClass<T>
{
    // obj.mymember = o for myclass
    public static void SetMember(string membername, object o, ref T obj)
    { 
    }
}
```

Can I do this with Reflection API ?

I have a generic class and I want to set a member of an instance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is it always a property? Also, why are you passing `obj` by reference?

Comment: I have a myclass object obj and I want to set mymember as 5. Is it possible to make it so with MySetterClass<myclass> in a different way by not passing it by ref ? It is always property and if it could be done in any other ways, I would like to hear them :)

Comment: You know, the Reflection code is the same regardless of whether it's generic.

Comment: you don't need to make it ref to modify the object.  You only need to make it ref if you plan on modifying the variable referencing the object.  If you are just changing a property, then the ref is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can, but I'd warn against it.  You are essentially doing an end-run around the type safety system, and there are a lot of pitfalls there.

If you must, the code is something like this, assuming that the member in question is a Property and not a Field:

```
typeof(T).GetProperty(membername).SetValue(obj, o);
```

Comment: You can use `obj.GetType()` instead of `typeof(T)` and it won't matter if it's generic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.  However, if you can do it without reflection, that would be best, since reflection is slow, cumbersome and harder to read and might indicate that your design is flawed.

I have to ask what your ultimate goal is with this code?  Do you really want to just have a method that sets a member based on a string naming that member?  Or do you want to be able to set a member on a generic type, but you know what it is at compile time?  If it's the latter, then using [generic constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) would something worth looking into.  They allow the compiler to know the members on an object of a generic type at compile time.